# Selenium - how to select a value from a dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium and I'm trying to get a value from a dropdown menu, specifically after I open the menu I'd like to select the "40" for a shoe size. This is the html code

https://i.postimg.cc/Bn3Nhv26/codicehtml.png

I tried with this code but it doesn't get the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='_6G4BGa _6yVObe _7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi FxZV-M sgIQH4 OXMl2N oW5DLR JT3_zV ZkIJC- Md_Vex JCuRr_ UTtITa _0xLoFW FCIprz pVrzNP KRmOLG NuVH8Q' and @for='size-picker-NI111A0ZB-A110085000']").click()
```

Also I tried to think about a different approach because I want the code to work on all items, first get all the options from the menu and then select the one I want, but again after I get the values I don't know how to keep going

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

# `dropdown_id` is the HTML id of the dropdown input
selector = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//*[@id='%s']" % dropdown_id)
# `value` is the value of the option in the dropdown you want to select
selector.select_by_value(value)
```

Note that you may have to wait until the element is loaded using a `WebDriverWait` with `visibility_of_element_located`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I tried your code but once I put the dropdownid it gives me an error "NameError: name 'size' is not defined" and it doesn't work

Comment: @Cecib can you paste the code you used?

Comment: I used this code, there was one ')' missing and if i put it before the percentage it doesnt give me the NameError but still doesn't work: `selector = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(r"//*[@id='%s']") % size-picker-NI111A0ZB-A110085000)
selector.select_by_value('NI111A0ZB-A110085000')`

Comment: I also tried to find other ways and there's one code working but it always select the second option on the menu and I wasn't able to redirect it `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'MU8FaS _0xLoFW VuYQuj parent _78xIQ-')]").click()` that's the tag that contains all the options

Comment: @Cecib The `%` is a string formatting operation in python, so it needs to be next to the string it's formatting to work.  Also, it looks like you are mixing up the ID of the dropdown and the value of the option you want to select.  try using my sample code and assign values to the variables `dropdown_id` and `value`; it will make your code easier to read and debug.